# is there any risk of exploited gadgets causing compromise?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

Demon the Descent p187

> Whatever the change, an Exploited gadget is
>   never mistaken for mundane. At best a Demon might be able
>   to pass one off as a prop or toy, but that is unlikely to fool a
>   savvy agent.

p188

> Despite the risks, these gadgets do carry some advantages
>   over raw Exploits. They do not evoke a compromise when
>   activated

So they don't look normal, for example I'm thinking of having a character with a jacket that is Tron-esque and has *Deep Pockets*. Her general explanation might be that it's a cool looking running jacket, that the lights are just to make sure she stays safe in the dark.

But wearing this thing in public causes no risk of compromise? Hunter angels can't tell? stigmatics? I feel like I'm missing something, and that there is a risk to wearing them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### There are risks to using an Exploited gadget, but causing a Compromise isn't one of them.

As detailed, Exploited items look unearthly when examined and have the potential to explode with aetheric energy and cause Glitches. (Page 188 - That's the part that stigmatics and hunter angels might notice.) However, using one explicitly says it does not cause a Compromise check.

Comment: I thought embedded gadget required the use of an embed? and you couldn't use an exploit (deep pockets is an exploit, IIRC)

Comment: You're right, xeno. Suggestion withdrawn.